# NLP: how can I transform a string into a sequence of numbers that represent it's label

Tags: python, nlp, label, sequence

I'm a beginner and I am trying to figure out how to approach an NLP problem. All help is much appreciated.

How can I transform a string into a label.

For example if I have the string " I liked this movie very much" and its label is {positive: 1} I would like to make the entire string represent this label. It should look something like this: "I like this movie very much" --> 1 1 1 1 1 1 . Each "1" representing a word from the sentence that's labeled as positive.

I am not sure where to start. I did extensive research online and couldn't find anything to help me get this done or even started. Any links and/or code suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a an input data structure along the lines of

```
reviews = [
    ('I liked this movie very much', 1), # positive sentiment
    ('I hated this movie', 0) # negative sentiment
]
```

To assign each word in the string with the same value as the whole string, you need to split the string. You can save the data in a new list structure. Try something like:

```
split_sentences = []
for sentence, sentiment in reviews:
    split_sentence = sentence.split()
    split_sentences.append([(word, sentiment) for word in split_sentence])
```

Your output of `split_sentences` will be

```
[[('I', 1), ('liked', 1), ('this', 1), ('movie', 1), ('very', 1), ('much', 1)],
 [('I', 0), ('hated', 0), ('this', 0), ('movie', 0)]]
```

If you literally just need a list of one label per word (substring), you can do

```
>>> for sentence, sentiment in reviews:
...     split_sentence = sentence.split()
...     sentiment_per_word = [sentiment for word in split_sentence]
...     print(sentiment_per_word)
... 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] # "I liked this movie very much"
[0, 0, 0, 0] # "I hated this movie"
```

Comment: Thank you jutta. Would you mind clarifying how that would work with a csv file? I tried the same code just changing the "reviews" to my data frame (pandas dataframe of a csv file with 7 features). I selected only the text column and the label column and tried to do the same split but I get an error. ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @Sonic_Tyo It would help if you posted what code you have so far.